# how do I set an app path to get the image I upload on flask?

Tags: python, flask, path, src

I am working on a flask project and having a hard time getting the image I uploaded.

```
appPath = os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'app')

trnsourceRoot = os.path.join(appPath, 'static/trnsource')
```

this is in my `index.py`

```
websvr

+trnsvr
|
\--trn_db.py

+app
|
\--main
   |
   --index.py

\--static
   |
   --trnsource
```

I checked where does my file upload on

`C:\mirae\facnroll_aws_210215\app\static\trnsource\F21021701\M21021700`

but I am getting a 404 error when the image is loaded on the web.

how do I solve this?
If need more information, please ask me further questions to clarify.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I would print both `appPath` and `trnsourceRoot` then you will probably see what is going wrong

Comment: I did and it helped me thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that actually the path when I upload the picture was misleading and I fixed it by running python on the right path.

in `index.py`

I had `appPath = os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'app')` and it set the current python directory as the appPath.

Originally

[image: original path python was executed]
the python was executed on the path above.

On the visual code terminal, I had to do `cd websvr` which is the subfolder.

[image]

I did `python run.py` and it resolved the problem.